# How do Apache camel / Java client connected to topic endpoint in solace

Tags: solace

In our setup, consumer publishes the messages on topic and a topic endpoint created in solace to subscribe to the topic. As a consumer/client we need to 
Connect to topic endpoint so that only those messages Stays on the queue that consumer is interested in.
My question is what is the connection string to connect with solace endpoint. I keep getting an error that JNDI name of [test_sample_topic_endpoint]
Not found in the default context. 
I am new to solace.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does everything work when you subscribe to the topic directly? Does everything work if you hardcode the endpoint name (skip JNDI)? Are you using selectors?

Comment: Can you provide the full logs that you are seeing?

Comment: Normally you should create a queue in Solace which subscribe to the topic(s) you're interested, and then you connect your client to the queue. It is possible a client to subscribe directly to the topic but in case you're client is disconnected,  the messages posted in topics are lost for that client (while they stay in the queue).